# what can i do to get my african violets to bloom better

Tags: houseplants, flowers

I water from the bottom, use fertilizer & grow under led lights ,they are healthy but rarely flower ,   what can i do to increase flower growth?

Comment: I water/fertilize weekly. Grow under partial sunlight. They've bloomed pretty much constantly for years, except when I forget their regular watering. Could be the light too. They're kind of picky about that.